# How do I make the debugger break when an exception is thrown in D?

Tags: debugging, gdb, d, lldb

When debugging D code that fails due to an uncaught exception, the exception mechanism unrolls the stack all the way back and then prints a stack trace, leaving us with the somewhat less than helpful:

```
(gdb) bt
No stack.
```

The stack trace gives us the line the exception was thrown from, but that's not especially helpful if it doesn't throw until a few thousand iterations in.  It would be quite useful to be able to set the debugger to break at the point of an exception whenever one is thrown.

At the moment, the only documentation out there on this seems to be a few posts on the dlang mailing lists.  I've found a few approaches that work with my setup, and have included them in my own answer, but for the benefit of others with this problem, I'm hoping we can get a more comprehensive answer that contains approaches for any combination of { dmd, gdc, ldc } x { gdb, lldb }.

Comment: What really grinds my gears about this is there's an easy solution of setting an internal variable so all uncaught exceptions are trapped by the debugger and caught ones work normally, would work on all debuggers, all compilers, all operating systems by just passing a command line arg to the program you run... but they never merged the PR despite there seemingly being nothing wrong with it. https://github.com/dlang/druntime/pull/2035

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe Even better would be if they mandated that _d_throw must exist with that name on all implementations, since it wouldn't require a recompile.  But if nothing else, your `rt_trapExceptions` hack gives us *something* that works with ldc.

Comment: But you don't actually want to break on _d_throw, even if it exists, because that breaks on ALL thrown exceptions, including ones caught in the program. The beauty of trapExceptions is it only traps *uncaught* exceptions, so you don't have to keep telling it to continue on ordinary, handled cases. (well sometimes you want it to break on a throw anyway, but you can break on the specific line of the throw instead of on all still)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since [DMD/DRuntime 2.082.0](https://dlang.org/changelog/2.082.0.html#exceptions-opt) this is possible by passing the `--DRT-trapException=0` flag to your program. The PR that Adam linked in the comments got merged for this.

With that addition you can also force it in your code with a prettier solution than the `rt_trapExceptions` code:

```d
extern(C) __gshared string[] rt_options = [ "trapExceptions=0" ];
```

You can read more about configuring the runtime options here: https://dlang.org/phobos/rt_config.html

---

Before that you were able to set rt_trapExceptions in a custom main as described in [This Week in D: August 7, 2016](https://arsdnet.net/this-week-in-d/2016-aug-07.html):

```d
extern extern(C) __gshared bool rt_trapExceptions;
extern extern(C) int _d_run_main(int, char**, void*);

extern(C) int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    rt_trapExceptions = false;
    return _d_run_main(argc, argv, &_main);
}

int _main() {
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of these were tested on Linux. The -g flag was passed to all three compilers.  The -d-debug flag was also passed to ldc, for all the good it did.

## gdb

#### (gdb) break _d_throwdwarf

- Works on linux + dmd
- Does not work on linux + gdc
- Does not work on linux + ldc

#### (gdb) break _d_throwc

- unknown, but the druntime source seems to suggest that this is _d_throwdwarf for win32 and win64.  Anyone with a Windows system want to test that?

#### (gdb) break object.Throwable.this

- Works on linux + dmd
- Works on linux + gdc
- Does not work on linux + ldc

#### (gdb) catch throw|catch|signal

- Does not work on linux + dmd or linux + gdc

## lldb

#### (lldb) b _d_throwdwarf

- works on linux + dmd

Comment: All the symbol-breakpoint methods above should work with lldb the same as with gdb (except you would either use `b <symbol_name>` or `break set -n <symbol_name>`.  lldb doesn't currently have any language support for D so the exception breakpoint doesn't support D exceptions.

Comment: @JimIngham `b _d_throwdwarf` works if it was compiled with dmd (added to the list; thank you), but `b object.Throwable.this` gets "an unable to resolve location" across all compilers.

Comment: What is object.Throwable.this?  That doesn't look like a C or C++ symbol name.

Comment: @JimIngham It's a function that is called for all exceptions when compiled under dmd or gdc.  (I also tried `b object::Throwable::this` in case the different syntax was throwing lldb off, with the same results.)

Comment: So this thing is a D symbol?  Does D have some name mangling scheme?  If so then to set a breakpoint lldb would have to know how to translate the D syntax name to the actual mangled symbol name (which it can't do at present since it knows nothing about D).  But if you can figure out the actual symbol name (as shown by nm or whatever your favorite symbol dumper is) then you should be able to break on that mangled name.